# Is there a lazy `filter` in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Python one can use `if` in the list comprehension to filter out elements. In Julia is there a lazy `filter` equivalent?

```
for x in filter(x->x<2, 1:3)
println(x)
end
```

works and prints only `1` but `filter(x->x<2, 1:3)` is eager and so may not be desirable for billions of records.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this just like in Python:

```
julia> function f()
           for x in (i for i in 1:10^9 if i == 10^9)
               println(x)
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time f()
1000000000
  3.293702 seconds (139.87 k allocations: 7.107 MiB)

julia> @time f()
1000000000
  3.224707 seconds (11 allocations: 352 bytes)
```

and you see that it does not allocate. But it is faster to just perform a filter test inside the loop without using a generator:

```
julia> function g()
           for x in 1:10^9
               x == 10^9 && println(x)
           end
       end
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time g()
1000000000
  2.098305 seconds (53.49 k allocations: 2.894 MiB)

julia> @time g()
1000000000
  2.094018 seconds (11 allocations: 352 bytes)
```

**Edit** Finally you can use `Iterators.filter`:

```
julia> function h()
          for x in Iterators.filter(==(10^9), 1:10^9)
              println(x)
          end
       end
h (generic function with 1 method)

julia>

julia> @time h()
1000000000
  0.390966 seconds (127.96 k allocations: 6.599 MiB)

julia> @time h()
1000000000
  0.311650 seconds (12 allocations: 688 bytes)
```

which in this case will be fastest (see also https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/iterators/#Iteration-utilities-1).

You might also want to check out https://github.com/JuliaCollections/IterTools.jl.

**EDIT 2**

Sometimes Julia is more powerful than you would think. Check this out:

```
julia> function g2()
          for x in 1:1_000_000_000
              x == 1_000_000_000 && println(x)
          end
       end
g2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia>

julia> @time g2()
1000000000
  0.029332 seconds (62.91 k allocations: 3.244 MiB)

julia> @time g2()
1000000000
  0.000636 seconds (11 allocations: 352 bytes)
```

and we see that the compiler has essentially compiled out all our computations.

In essence - in the earlier example constant propagation kicked in and replaced `10^9` by `1_000_000_000` in the `Iterators.filter` example.

Therefore we have to devise a smarter test. Here it goes:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> function f_rand(x)
           s = 0.0
           for v in (v for v in x if 0.1 < v < 0.2)
               s += v
           end
           s
       end
f_rand (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function g_rand(x)
           s = 0.0
           for v in x
               if 0.1 < v < 0.2
                   s += v
               end
           end
           s
       end
g_rand (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function h_rand(x)
           s = 0.0
           for v in Iterators.filter(v -> 0.1 < v < 0.2, x)
               s += v
           end
           s
       end
h_rand (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = rand(10^6);

julia> @btime f_rand($x)
  2.032 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
14922.291597613703

julia> @btime g_rand($x)
  1.804 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
14922.291597613703

julia> @btime h_rand($x)
  2.035 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
14922.291597613703
```

And now we get what I was originally expecting (a plain loop with `if` is the fastest).

Comment: Any idea why `Iterator.filter` is so much faster?

Comment: Ah - the compiler optimizations kick in. I will expand on them in the answer.

Comment: I was thrown by `for x in (i for i in 1:10^9 if i == 10^9)` I thought this would be fine `for x for i in 1:10^9 if i == 10^9; #do stuff; end`. But this is awesome!

Comment: *"And now we get what I was originally expecting (a plain loop with if is the fastest)."*  It's interesting to see how close these numbers are, though.  Are you sure the difference is statistically significant?

Comment: You can benchmark yourself :), also changing the size of `x` (different hardware might give a bit different results), but given my tests `g_rand` will be fastest, `f_rand` and `h_rand` are comparable (for large `x` `h_rand` seems to be a bit faster).